# Create template page for showing jpg's from direct links

Tags: php, css, templates, jpeg

When I click on a link to an jpg image, the browser will usually open a new tab, and diplay it on a white background.
I want to use a generated php page, that will diplay the image, so I could use css on it.
I could put every image on a single php site, and simply link to that, but I want it to happen automatically, once any image link is clicked.

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/images/image.jpg">Link</a>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: is better to reformulate your question and why not add some screenshots

Comment: It depends on how you've implemented the image links. Or do you mean the browser's right click -> show image feature?

Comment: like this: `code` <a href="http://www.website.com/images/image.jpg">Link</a> `code`

Comment: maybe a lightbox (like colorbox openseource) will do what you need and also you can send the image name to a generic page by a get param

Comment: No, I dont want to open the image in a lightbox. It has to be a new tab/page.

Comment: see Juhana answer like i have said by a $_get parameter by sending image name or the id if it's from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the links to `<a href="http://example.com/showimage.php?image=images/image.jpg">Link</a>` or similar, create a  showimage.php page that has the formatting you want and use `$_GET[ 'image' ]` to get the requested image's url.

Comment: can be simplified by `showimage.php?image=image.jpg` , adding the path later

Comment: But that simplyfication would only work, if all images are in the same folder right? (Which is not the case for me)